# Retrieve all properties of env in Jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to print all available properties (and their values) in `env` object inside Jenkinsfile.

When I do

```
print env
```

I get:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl@112cebc2
```

So it looks like `toString` is not implemented there, how can I access properties that are in this object if I don't know their names?

Comment: Does `println env.overriddenEnvironment` shed more light on it?

Comment: It gives me `null`

Comment: Same with `env.environment `?

Comment: yes, it gives `null` also

Comment: I've posted an answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083285/how-to-list-all-env-properties-within-jenkins-pipeline-job which might be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all \`env\` properties within jenkins pipeline job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083285/how-to-list-all-env-properties-within-jenkins-pipeline-job)

Answer (score 22):

Make sure you're not running the pipeline script in sandboxed mode and you should be able to use:

```
env.getEnvironment()
```

Note, if you're running in sandbox mode in a pipeline, you should approve the method at the script approval page: `http://jenkins-host/scriptApproval/`

Answer (score 9):

To retrieve all env properties using a Jenkinsfile written in either declarative or scripted DSL you can use:

```
sh 'env'
```

or

```
sh 'printenv'
```

Answer (score 4):

As said over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42138466/618253

The declarative pipeline way of doing things:

```
node {
   echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'env')
}
```