# How to list all `env` properties within jenkins pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Given a jenkins build pipeline, jenkins injects a variable `env` into the `node{}`. Variable `env` holds environment variables and values.

***I want to print *all* `env` properties within the jenkins pipeline. However, I do no not know *all* `env` properties ahead of time.***

For example, environment variable `BRANCH_NAME` can be printed with code

```
node {
    echo "BRANCH_NAME is " + ${env.BRANCH_NAME}
    ...
```

But again, I don't know all variables ahead of time. I want code that handles that, something like

```groovy
node {
    for(e in env){
        echo e + " is " + ${e}
    }
    ...
```

which would echo something like

```
 BRANCH_NAME is myBranch2
 CHANGE_ID is 44
 ...
```

---

I used Jenkins 2.1 for this example.

Comment: env is a map. Did you try normal iteration? like  -- env.each{
println it
}

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836806/retrieve-all-properties-of-env-in-jenkinsfile

Comment: try `env.each { name, value -> println "Name: $name -> Value $value" }`

Comment: Afaik env just encapsulates the environment variables. I dont think you can loop through it. Try 'sh env' on linux/ 'bat set' on windows.

Comment: @Renato @Jayan per my comment below, `env.each { name, value -> println "Name: $name -> Value $value" }` prints `Name: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl@45c2d1ee -> Value null`.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979 That's because Pipeline breaks Groovy closures. If you right it old-Java style (that is, `new ClassName() { ... }`), it should work. Or you run it on a method tagged `@NonCPS`, then closures will work inside that too.

Comment: the 'env' object ist NOT a map, but some class object.
i tried it out on a Jenkins pipeline script.
calls like ".each()" will result in "Name: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl@633862d -> Value null" whilst calls like ".containsKey(...)" will result in "hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl.containsKey() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [...]"

Answer (score 160):

According to [Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#working-with-the-environment) for [declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline):

```
sh 'printenv'
```

For Jenkins [scripted pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline):

```
echo sh(script: 'env|sort', returnStdout: true)
```

The above also sorts your env vars for convenience.

Comment: `printenv` is just a shell command that prints the environment, nothing specific to Jenkins. Without arguments it is equivalent to `env` without arguments. I'm pretty sure `sh 'printenv | sort'` will work in DCL or scripted pipeline.

Comment: Tested and `sh 'printenv | sort'` does in fact work for a Jenkins declarative pipeline; fwiw `sh 'env | sort'` also works (Both tested on Jenkins ver. 2.46.1). I originally mentioned `sh 'printenv'` because it was referenced in official Jenkins documentation.

Comment: If you lose the returnStdout:true then you don't need the echo;  It's just printing what the shell script printed already.

Answer (score 96):

Another, more concise way:

```
node {
    echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'env')
    // ...
}
```

cf. https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script

Comment: Replace `sh` with `bat` and `env` with `set` under Windows.

Comment: For the "sh" case I use 'env | sort' because it drives me crazy that the it isn't ordered by key.

Comment: under windows:  echo bat(returnStdout: true, script: 'set')

Answer (score 44):

The following works:

```
@NonCPS
def printParams() {
  env.getEnvironment().each { name, value -> println "Name: $name -> Value $value" }
}
printParams()
```

Note that it will most probably fail on first execution and require you approve various groovy methods to run in jenkins sandbox. This is done in "manage jenkins/in-process script approval"

The list I got included:

- BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME
- BUILD_ID
- BUILD_NUMBER
- BUILD_TAG
- BUILD_URL
- CLASSPATH
- HUDSON_HOME
- HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE
- HUDSON_URL
- JENKINS_HOME
- JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE
- JENKINS_URL
- JOB_BASE_NAME
- JOB_NAME
- JOB_URL

Comment: This doesn't work: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: each on a CPS-transformed closure is not yet supported`

Comment: Did you make sure to include the `@NonCPS`?

Comment: This is the best answer because it will work outside of a *node* block. Thanks so much for this.

Comment: Not a good solution, `env.getEnvironment()` is not whitelisted to be used in pipeline scripts: `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.actions.EnvironmentAction getEnvironment`.

Comment: As written in the answer:
Note that it will most probably fail on first execution and ***require you approve various groovy methods to run in jenkins sandbox.*** 
This is done in "manage jenkins/in-process script approval"

Comment: This is a good solution, because not in all cases you have node{} notation. If you want to parse Jenkins parameters before initializing node from shared library, this solution will work, otherwise sh('env') will fail. But @NonCPS is not needed here.

Answer (score 15):

You can accomplish the result using `sh`/`bat` step and `readFile`:

```
node {
    sh 'env > env.txt'
    readFile('env.txt').split("\r?\n").each {
        println it
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `env.getEnvironment()` returns very limited map of environment variables.

Comment: `sh 'env > env.txt'` works well and includes environment variables created by the shell process. `env.getEnvironment()` shows only the Jenkins set environment variables which are a subset of that seen in `sh 'env'` technique. Also, it needs script security approval `method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.actions.EnvironmentAction getEnvironment`. The `env.each { name, value -> println "Name: $name -> Value $value" }` recommended by @Renato @Jayan only prints `Name: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl@45c2d1ee -> Value null`.

Comment: Nice!!! Being able to print all env vars helped me discover that Jenkins 2 sets a JOB_BASE_NAME var contains the job name sans the folder it lives in.

Comment: a version that works on windows would be awesome as well :)

Comment: @Bas Hamer for a windows version try to replace "sh" by "bat"

Comment: Gives me an error 

    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Calling public static java.lang.Object org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(java.lang.Object,groovy.lang.Closure) on a CPS-transformed closure is not yet supported (JENKINS-26481); encapsulate in a @NonCPS method, or use Java-style loops

Comment: There are a few other options over here that are a bit more concise, also I would note what types of Jenkins pipelines this works for, as it makes a big difference.

Answer (score 15):

Why all this complicatedness?

```
sh 'env'
```

does what you need (under *nix)

Comment: This requires a node block to execute.  For my use-case I need to process what environment the node will have then spin a node up based on certain criteria.

Answer (score 14):

Cross-platform way of listing all environment variables:

```
if (isUnix()) {
    sh env
}
else {
    bat set
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's a quick script you can add as a pipeline job to list all environment variables:

```
node {
    echo(env.getEnvironment().collect({environmentVariable ->  "${environmentVariable.key} = ${environmentVariable.value}"}).join("\n"))
    echo(System.getenv().collect({environmentVariable ->  "${environmentVariable.key} = ${environmentVariable.value}"}).join("\n"))
}
```

This will list both system and Jenkins variables.

Answer (score 11):

The **pure Groovy** solutions that read the global `env` variable don't print all environment variables (e. g. they are missing variables from the `environment` block, from `withEnv` context and most of the machine-specific variables from the OS). Using shell steps it is possible to get a more complete set, but that requires a `node` context, which is not always wanted.

Here is a solution that uses the [`getContext`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#getcontext-get-contextual-object-from-internal-apis) step to retrieve and print the complete set of environment variables, including pipeline parameters, for the current context.

**Caveat:** Doesn't work in Groovy sandbox. You can use it from a trusted shared library though.

```
def envAll = getContext( hudson.EnvVars )
echo envAll.collect{ k, v -> "$k = $v" }.join('\n')
```

Comment: This is the best agentless solution!

Answer (score 8):

I use Blue Ocean plugin and did not like each environment entry getting its own block. I want *one* block with all the lines.

**Prints poorly:**

```
sh 'echo `env`'
```

**Prints poorly:**

```
sh 'env > env.txt'
for (String i : readFile('env.txt').split("\r?\n")) {
    println i
}
```

**Prints well:**

```
sh 'env > env.txt'
sh 'cat env.txt'
```

**Prints well:** (as mentioned by @mjfroehlich)

```
echo sh(script: 'env', returnStdout: true)
```

Answer (score 6):

Show all variable in Windows system and Unix system is different, you can define a function to call it every time.

```
def showSystemVariables(){    
   if(isUnix()){
     sh 'env'
   } else {
     bat 'set'
   }
}
```

I will call this function first to show all variables in all pipline script

```
stage('1. Show all variables'){
     steps {
         script{            
              showSystemVariables()
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest and quickest way is to use following url to print all environment variables

http://localhost:8080/env-vars.html/

Comment: Also useful: `https://jenkins.yoururl.com/pipeline-syntax/globals`

Answer (score 4):

Includes both system and build environment vars:

```
sh script: "printenv", label: 'print environment variables'
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers above, are now antiquated due to new pipeline syntax.  Below prints out the environment variables.

```
script {
        sh 'env > env.txt'
        String[] envs = readFile('env.txt').split("\r?\n")

        for(String vars: envs){
            println(vars)
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. You need to have it in a script block.
2. They are depreciating the 'groovy style' loop.

Comment: The `for` with a closure will also cause problems without a `@NonCPS` annotation.

Answer (score 3):

ref: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/

```
node {
    sh 'printenv'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sh 'printenv'`

```
 stage('1') {
    sh "printenv" 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you really want to loop over the `env` list just do:

```
def envs = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'env').split('\n')
envs.each { name  ->
    println "Name: $name"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this is the most easiest way:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'master'
        }
    }   
    stages {
        stage('hello world') {
            steps {
                sh 'env'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all variables from your jenkins instance. Just visit:

- ${jenkins_host}/env-vars.html
- ${jenkins_host}/pipeline-syntax/globals

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you needed that in form of a script, but if someone else just want to have a look through the Jenkins GUI, that list can be found by selecting the "Environment Variables" section in contextual left menu of every build
Select project => Select build => Environment Variables

[image]

Comment: This is not always available.

Comment: I don't think it's available for Jenkinsfiles at all. Screenshot looks like a freestyle build.

Answer (score 1):

If we don't want to have node assigned but print env vars this can help:

```
print env.getEnvironment()
```

Tested on Jenkins version: Jenkins 2.426.1

Answer (score 0):

another way to get exactly the output mentioned in the question:

```
envtext= "printenv".execute().text
envtext.split('\n').each
{   envvar=it.split("=")
    println envvar[0]+" is "+envvar[1]
}
```

This can easily be extended to build a map with a subset of env vars matching a criteria:

```
envdict=[:]
envtext= "printenv".execute().text
envtext.split('\n').each
{   envvar=it.split("=")
    if (envvar[0].startsWith("GERRIT_"))
        envdict.put(envvar[0],envvar[1])
}    
envdict.each{println it.key+" is "+it.value}
```