# Environment variable in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there any environment variable available for getting the Jenkins Pipeline Title?

I know we can use `$JOB_NAME` to get title for a freestyle job, 
but is there anything that can be used for getting Pipeline name?

Comment: You can have a look at this answer if you want to see the variables that are available in your pipeline.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42138466/1238300

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can access the same environment variables from groovy using the same names (e.g. `JOB_NAME` or `env.JOB_NAME`).

From the documentation:

> Environment variables are accessible from Groovy code as env.VARNAME or simply as VARNAME. You can write to such properties as well (only using the env. prefix):
>
> ```
> env.MYTOOL_VERSION = '1.33'
> node {
>   sh '/usr/local/mytool-$MYTOOL_VERSION/bin/start'
> }
> ```
>
> These definitions will also be available via the REST API during the build or after its completion, and from upstream Pipeline builds using the build step.

For the rest of the documentation, click the "Pipeline Syntax" link from any Pipeline job
[image]

Comment: Thanks,
I used 
env.MyVariable and it works in my usecase now I can define environment variables from pipeline.

Thanks for saving some time for me.

Answer (score 43):

To avoid problems of side effects after changing `env`, especially using multiple nodes, it is better to set a temporary context.

One safe way to alter the environment is:

```
 withEnv(['MYTOOL_HOME=/usr/local/mytool']) {
    sh '$MYTOOL_HOME/bin/start'
 }
```

This approach does not poison the env after the command execution.