# Jenkins Global Environment Variable

Tags: jenkins, global-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I am aware that I can set a global environment variable in Manage Jenkins --> Configure System --> Global properties.

But I wanted to set the global environment variable in a Jenkins Pipeline Job that shared among all Jenkins Job.

Please help

Comment: Do you want to set the variable by some scripting (e.g. script console) or does it really need to be a pipeline job? I‘m curious about the use case.

Comment: @JoergS Pipeline job will be easier for the developer to build the job without going into the script console or system configuration.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604854/environment-variable-in-jenkins-pipeline).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment variable in Jenkins Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604854/environment-variable-in-jenkins-pipeline)