# Use Jenkins Environment Variable to automatically generate job name?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-job-builder

I am using Jenkins Job Generator Plugin to generate the job.

Scenario: Testing is a main project. After successful completion and whenever a developer updates the repository it invokes Jenkins Job Generator Project and this job is responsible for creating the child job.

So in this case i need to update the child job name. To this end I am trying to use a Jenkins environment variable like this:

Generated Job Name: `PROJECT_NAME - "${SVN_REVISION}"`

But after the execution of Jenkins Job Generator it's creating child job but name of job is like:  `PROJECT_NAME - "${SVN_REVISION}"`

The Child job name is expected to be: `Testing-8890`

Can anyone tell me how to use environment variable in job configuration page?

Thank You

Comment: try with "printenv" and check all the environment variable available, this will help to get the proper name of the environment  variable.

Comment: Hello, I am using windows os. can you please tell me how to check environment  variables.

Comment: Fire only "printenv" in Build Section of your job configuration (select execute shell) or you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083285/how-to-list-all-env-properties-within-jenkins-pipeline-job

Comment: Is this a freestyle job or a pipeline job?

Comment: Job Type is Job Generator.