# Jenkins Android build fails - can't build libwebviewchromium.so

Tags: android, jenkins, android-source, android-5.1.1-lollipop, webviewchromium

A bit of advice or idea is needed.

I am trying to build Android 5.1.1 Lollipop with Jenkins. But it fails to build libwebviewchromium.so:

```
...
out/target/product/generic/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/blink/bindings/core/v8/V8SVGNumber.cpp:55: error: undefined reference to 'blink::SVGNumberTearOff::setValue(float, blink::ExceptionState&)'
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/third_party_WebKit_Source_core_webcore_generated_gyp_intermediates/SVGElementFactory.cpp:383: error: undefined reference to 'blink::SVGMetadataElement::create(blink::Document&)'
external/chromium_org/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/svg/SVGNumberTearOff.h:45: error: undefined reference to 'blink::SVGNumberTearOff::SVGNumberTearOff(WTF::PassRefPtr<blink::SVGNumber>, blink::SVGElement*, blink::PropertyIsAnimValType, blink::QualifiedName const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libwebviewchromium_intermediates/LINKED/libwebviewchromium.so] Error 1
```

At the same time, when I try to build it manually, it succeeds:

```
. build/envsetup.sh
set_stuff_for_environment
lunch zh2_qemu_eng
make clean
make -j24
```

I wonder how it comes that the same operation can be successful when using a console and fail when using Jenkins. Could you please share your ideas with me?

P.S. The build machine has 24GB of RAM and 15GB swap file, and a 512 GB SSD flash disk (62% available). The OS is Ubuntu 14.04LTS, 64 bit.

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         24021      22079       1942         75       4778       8768
-/+ buffers/cache:       8532      15488
Swap:        16036        345      15691
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.
We copied the Jenkins/AOSP setup from another server, and something was wrong with the copy.
The cleanup of the ccache solved the problem. After performing "ccache -c" command, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

> I wonder how it comes that the same operation can be successful when using a console and fail when using Jenkins.

Because Jenkins might not run with the same user (or on the same workstation, if the agent executing the job is a separate machine)

Double-check if there are any environment variable differences between:

- your command-line, where you can successfully run your command (type `env` after your commands)
- the [environment variables you can see associated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51300677/6309) with your (failed) job

For instance, a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` difference could explain the discrepancy between the two builds.

Comment: Are there any other environment variables I should pay attention to, besides LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: @VladimirLindemann look for any difference between the list of environment variables in your bash session as opposed to the one in a Jenkins job.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have all the **header files included** and **libraries linked** at the time of compilation. *Undefined Reference* errors primarily arise due to these two reasons.

Answer (score 2):

user `jenkins` has it's own `~/.bashrc`, which might lack environmental variables.

temporarily enable login shell for `jenkins`, setup the environment, then disable it again.

when being able to manually build as user `jenkins`, it should also build when automated.

Comment: Actually, I tried building using that user. But my build system uses a complicated script for Jenkins. That script sets up all the environment variables. I should compare these thoroughly, I think.

Comment: @VladimirLindemann just run `printenv` with the regular user and with user jenkins. comparing the actual result of the scripts is easier than comparing the scripts. there has to be some difference - possibly different permissions. adding the regular user into group jenkins might also help, if this is the case - because it grants user jenkins group access, where it otherwise wouldn't have access.