# How to retrieve Jenkins environment from Groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am setting a Jenkins. I am programming with my pipeline using **Global Pipeline Libraries** to be able to increase reusability. Scripts are object oriented and in Groovy. Information about the concept can be found  [there](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)

I don't manage to retrieve the Jenkins specific environment using my library script. I would like for instance to access:

- Build_ID
- Build_Number
- JOB_Name
- Workspace_path

I tryied to use env.WORKSPACE but it is returning a NULL. I manage to retrieve it directly in the pipeline but this is not my goal.

I am using Jenkins 2.303.1.

Comment: I would say there are multiple options provided in answers to [this 5-year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37083285/598141)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you write your scripts, you might need to inject the Jenkins environment. For example, if you go for a more object oriented way

```
// vars/whatever.groovy
import ...

@Field
def myTool = new MyTool(this)
```

```
// src/.../MyTool.groovy
import ...

class MyTool {
    private final jenkins

    MyTool(jenkins) {
        this.jenkins = jenkins
    }

    def echoBuildNumber() {
        this.jenkins.echo(this.jenkins.env.BUILD_NUMBER)
    }
}
```

```
// Jenkinsfile
@Library(...)
node {
    echo env.BUILD_NUMBER             // echoes build number
    whatever.myTool.echoBuildNumber() // echoes build number
}
```

Comment: I run 1 to 1 this script and I got this result: 
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myTool for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Comment: What does the @Field do?

Comment: Make sure you're importing properly the shared library. You can find the docs of @Field at https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html

Answer (score 1):

So the env which you are looking for can be accessible using like this in groovy script

`${env.BUILD_NUMBER}`
`${env.JOB_NAME}`
`${env.WORKSPACE}`
`${env.BUILD_ID}`

Comment: This is not working in shared library