# Why don't env and env.getEnvironment() perfectly overlap in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

This question follows from reading [How to list all `env` properties within jenkins pipeline job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083285/how-to-list-all-env-properties-within-jenkins-pipeline-job).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41345704/5437543) to the linked question offers this solution that iterates through each element in `env.getEnvironment()`:

```
env.getEnvironment().each { name, value -> println "Name: $name -> Value $value" }
```

In my case, the output is:

```
Name: BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME -> Value #106
Name: BUILD_ID -> Value 106
Name: BUILD_NUMBER -> Value 106
Name: BUILD_TAG -> Value jenkins-wip-106
Name: BUILD_URL -> Value http://jenkins-server:8080/job/wip/106/
Name: CI -> Value true
Name: CLASSPATH -> Value 
Name: HUDSON_HOME -> Value /var/lib/jenkins
Name: HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE -> Value 15bd679c60fb6abe
Name: HUDSON_URL -> Value http://jenkins-server:8080/
Name: JENKINS_HOME -> Value /var/lib/jenkins
Name: JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE -> Value 19bd670c60fb6bbe
Name: JENKINS_URL -> Value http://jenkins-server:8080/
Name: JOB_BASE_NAME -> Value wip
Name: JOB_DISPLAY_URL -> Value http://jenkins-server:8080/job/wip/display/redirect
Name: JOB_NAME -> Value wip
Name: JOB_URL -> Value http://jenkins-server:8080/job/wip/
Name: RUN_ARTIFACTS_DISPLAY_URL -> Value http://jenkins-server:8080/job/wip/106/display/redirect?page=artifacts
Name: RUN_CHANGES_DISPLAY_URL -> Value http://jenkins-server:8080/job/wip/106/display/redirect?page=changes
Name: RUN_DISPLAY_URL -> Value http://jenkins-server:8080/job/wip/106/display/redirect
Name: RUN_TESTS_DISPLAY_URL -> Value http://jenkins-server:8080/job/wip/106/display/redirect?page=tests
```

I first noticed there is no `WORKSPACE`, in the above list but [there is a `env.WORKSPACE`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables).
I then noticed there's a handful of key/value pairs that are either direct members of `env` or members of the Map `env.getEnvironment()`.
E.g. `env.BUILD_ID` and `env.getEnvironment()['BUILD_ID']` both exist...
whereas `env.WORKSPACE` exists while `env.getEnvironment()['WORKSPACE']` does not...
and `env.CLASSPATH` does not exist whereas `env.getEnvironment()['CLASSPATH'] exists.

**What is the logical distinction between the "direct" member objects of `env` (e.g. `env.BUILD_ID`) and the members of `env.getEnvironment()`?**

Between "env" and "getEnvironnment", and the fact that they're different, the notion of "environment" in the context of Jenkins feels muddled -- perhaps if someone can explain why they're distinct, it'll make sense to me when and why I should get information from `env` vs. `env.getEnvironment()`.

I didn't see `env.getEnvironment()` or its distinction from `env`'s direct members documented at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables or {{my_jenkins_url}}/job/{{job}}/pipeline-syntax/globals