# jenkins BRANCH_NAME variable no longer working

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have this jenkinsfile that I run on jenkins

```
node("MacMiniSlave") {
  try{
  withEnv(["PATH=${env.HOME}/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin:${env.PATH}","http_proxy=http://proxy.singaporepower.com.sg","https_proxy=http://proxy.singaporepower.com.sg","LANG=en_US.UTF-8","LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8"]){
      sh "env"
      echo "My branch is: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
    }
    currentBuild.result='SUCCESS'
  }catch(Exception e){
    currentBuild.result="FAILURE"
    throw e
  }finally{
    step([$class: 'GitHubCommitNotifier', resultOnFailure:'FAILURE'])
  }
}
```

but the output from this is `My branch is: null`. Why is it so?

Comment: There's really a lot of important information that you haven't mentioned here. What makes you think it should be anything but null?

Comment: The environment of the Jenkins script may not be the same as the environment that the shell commands get executed with. You can [print out an environment dump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836806/retrieve-all-properties-of-env-in-jenkinsfile) to see which variables are available.

Comment: Having the same issue with Jenkins 2.46.3 :-(