# PowerShell environment variable in Jenkins Pipeline gives `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl@1b69f5bb:VARIABLE_NAME`

Tags: powershell, jenkins, command-line, jenkins-pipeline

Has anyone run into a problem when using PowerShell in a Jenkins Pipeline, where when you try to pull in an environmental variable (e.g., `$env:CHANGE_ID`), it evaluates to something like this?

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl@1b69f5bb:VARIABLE_NAME
```

It looks like someone else was running into the same problem in this question, but I'm not sure that it was answered there (they show how to print all environment variables, but not how to get a specific one when `toString` is not implemented):
[Retrieve all properties of env in Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836806/retrieve-all-properties-of-env-in-jenkinsfile)

My Jenkins pipeline file:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'jenkins_managed_windows'
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('SonarQube Analysis') {
      steps {
        powershell "dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:project-key /d:sonar.branch.name=$env:BRANCH_NAME"
      }
    }

    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        powershell 'dotnet build'
      }
    }

    stage('SonarQube End') {
      steps {
        powershell 'dotnet sonarscanner end'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The step with the environment variable gets run as:

```
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:project-key /d:sonar.branch.name=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl@54ee3a8:BRANCH_NAME
```

Interestingly, if I use single quoting:

```
powershell 'dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:project-key /d:sonar.branch.name=$env:BRANCH_NAME'
```

It doesn't even evaluate the environment variable at all, and just gets run as:

```
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:project-key /d:sonar.branch.name=$env:BRANCH_NAME
```

Comment: Single-quoted strings are not evaluated.

Comment: Try `powershell "dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:project-key /d:sonar.branch.name=$($env:BRANCH_NAME)"`

Comment: This gave me: `WorkflowScript: 11: illegal string body character after dollar sign;

   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 11, column 3.`

I then tried: `powershell "dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:project-key /d:sonar.branch.name=${env:BRANCH_NAME}"`, which ended up working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax forms `$env:BRANCH_NAME` and the equivalent `${env:BRANCH_NAME}` are *PowerShell* constructs, which means that in order to *pass them throug*h to PowerShell **in an interpolating *Groovy* string (`"..."`), you must `\`-escape the `$` character to prevent *Groovy* from interpreting the construct** up front:

```
powershell "dotnet sonarscanner begin ... /d:sonar.branch.name=\$env:BRANCH_NAME"
```

That said, given that your command contains no *Groovy* variables that need to be interpolated (it's safe and more robust to let *PowerShell* reference *environment* variables), **you can simply use a *literal* Groovy string, `'...'`, where `$` chars. destined for PowerShell need *no* escaping**:

```
powershell 'dotnet sonarscanner begin ... /d:sonar.branch.name=$env:BRANCH_NAME'
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

`"... $env:BRANCH_NAME"` in an interpolating Groovy string causes Groovy to interpolate variable `env` (since it is preceded by `$`), and treat `:BRANCH_NAME` as a literal.

Since `env` refers to the object that contains *all* environment variables, what you're seeing is the (unhelpful) stringification of that object, which is the class name (`org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl`) followed by an instance-specific hash code (`@54ee3a8`).

Using `${env.BRANCH_NAME}` would have worked - given that the value of environment variable `BRANCH_NAME` can be accessed as a property of the `env` object - but note that this means that *Groovy* interpolates the value *up front* and that PowerShell then only sees the *resulting value*.

In *simple* cases (environment-variable values without whitespace or special characters), `"${env.BRANCH_NAME}"` (up-front interpolation by Groovy) and `"\${env:BRANCH_NAME}"` (later interpretation by PowerShell) are interchangeable, but only the latter approach works robustly with all values.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. The output of the Jenkins Pipeline was just showing the command as `dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:project-key /d:sonar.branch.name=$env:BRANCH_NAME`, since Groovy wasn't interpolating the command. When it was actually run in PowerShell though it was using the actual environment variables though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out specifying the environment variable this way works:

```
powershell "dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:project-key /d:sonar.branch.name=${env:BRANCH_NAME}"
```

You can also use a period instead of a colon (`${env.BRANCH_NAME}`).

Comment: Inside `"..."`, you should `\ `-escape the `$` -  `\${env:BRANCH_NAME}` - which prevents Groovy from potentially interpreting the construct. By contrast, using `${env.BRANCH_NAME}` (note the `.`) causes Groovy to replace the construct with the _value_ of environment variable `BRANCH_NAME` _before_ PowerShell sees the resulting string. In simple cases the two approaches are interchangeable, but the latter approach can break if your command if the variable value contains whitespace or special characters.